# Offline crash reporting in Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I intentionally crashed my application when there was no WIFI to check whether the crash report is updated in Crashlytics and it didn't get updated as there was no WIFI. But when i turned on the wifi the crash didn't get reported. But if i again crash my application when the wifi is switched on. The crash report for this crash along with the crash which occurred when the wifi was off got updated. I'm not able to figure out the reason behind it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to ask Crashlytics support directly. Their SDK is closed source, so it is pretty much impossible to tell how the SDK exactly is intended to behave.

Comment: @kemi my app will be running continuously in the background so the launch function in delegate will be called only when we have a crash. So i'm not able to derive at a solution for this problem. so want to know how it works.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Marc from Crashlytics here. If the app crashes without an active network connection, the report will still be caught! We always send crash reports on launch when there's an active connection. If that fails, we'll queue it to send later. :)

Comment: my app will be running continuously in the background so the launch function in delegate will be called only when we have a crash. So i'm not able to derive at a solution for this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what did u mean by "launch" did u mean it has to hit "Application did finish launching" method in app delegate?

Comment: After Crashlytics.start() is called, a background thread will look for cached crash reports and attempt to send them. If there's no active network connection, the SDK will attempt to send the reports later during that execution of the app. The report isn't deleted from the device until it has been received by our servers, so you'll get the report eventually, once the app gets connectivity.

Comment: That is the exact problem i'm facing. when i get the connectivity even after 12 hours i'm not getting the crash reports?. Do you people send the reports on 3G or only on WIFI networks?. My app is an background application so the users wont open it often. Except for like once in a week or so. But it will be continually running in the background. I even tried it opening the app but then also i was not able to get the reports(i.e reports of the crashes which occurred when there was no WIFI network). I'm only getting the reports if there is a WIFI connection when the crash happens.

Comment: @marcr can I only upload crash file and logs only when user under WIFI connection? Thx

Comment: I see the logs when my device is offline saying that : `E CrashlyticsCore: Error occurred sending report com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionReport@fb1fb90` AS you said I should have received the reports when I connect the device to wifi or mobile data but I do not get any report. I need to find what did fabric want to send me as an error report. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Crashlytics is caching error reports and reporting them in batches.

> To reduce your users' network traffic, Crashlytics batches logged exceptions together and       sends them the next time the app launches. If you don't see logged exceptions in your Crashlytics web dashboard, try restarting your app!
>
> http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions

Comment: @wrapedspeed. Ya i know i have to restart the application. My app gets restarted after the crash because of VOIP call back. I just wanted to know if the app gets crashed when the user is not in wifi network and the app is restarted, but when he gets the wifi network then, does the reports are sent or should i have to wait for the app to crash when the user is in the wifi network in order to get the crash?