# How does crashlytics manage to upload crash-log even the crash happens in applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, crashlytics

As $title, just wondering how they do this.
This is what they say in their webpage 'Is there a quick way to force a crash?'
http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92522-is-there-a-quick-way-to-force-a-crash-

And I followed this, successfully got the crash-log in applicationDidFinishLaunching:.

Answer (score 1):

They only upload it, once the application is restarted.

They gather information before the crash, and send the crash log after a restart.

That is how I understood it.

See the answer from @marcr here: [Offline crash reporting in Crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613257/offline-crash-reporting-in-crashlytics)

Comment: They can send the crash log to their server in such a short time, even crashed in applicationDidFinishLaunching. Do not know what they do behind this super quick report feature.

Comment: But normally the first thing you do is [CrashLytics startWithAPIKey:]. And that is probably where they report the crashes. If you have crashes going on before you even called that method, even crashlytics probably wont report any crashes. To send a request should not be a problem, that happens in no time if it is lightweight. Waiting for the result and processing it, might take a while.

Comment: Did you try the "Advanced"-section on their webpage to force a crash? And to force it before you call the startWithAPIKey: ?