# Android: store crash data when offline

Tags: android, error-reporting

I'm looking for something like ACRA (Automated Crash Reporting for Android) https://github.com/ACRA/acra but it has to be able to store data, and send it once the user goes online.

Already read through suggestions on

[How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

but none of these says something about offline solutions. Anybody knows a solution that works offline and that I could use with my AWS account or a linux domestic server (raspberry pi)?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com)

> Marc from Crashlytics here. If the app crashes without an active network connection, the report will still be caught! We always send crash reports on launch when there's an active connection. If that fails, we'll queue it to send later. :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618098/1048340

Comment: Do you have any idea if I can trigger when the report is sent? My APP works mostly offline, but I have a sync button, which the user must be online to send and receive data. I'd like to send the reports when that happen if possible.