# Does Crashlytics Manage Offline Crashes.

Tags: exception, crash, crashlytics

Fabric Crashlytics is a very good facility to handle the **crashes** in Android and iOs. But I want to know does it handle Offline crashes. If yes then please give me an example in android so that I can apply it in my projects.

Comment: Hello, guys ! 

 I am searching alternate which can catch crashes when the Internet is not available in Mobile. please answer me ..

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics autosave crashing report into a cache If Network and Wi-Fi connectivity are not available. **There is no need to add additional code to get offline crashes **. Crashing error are sent them into crashlytics dashboard when mobile get again network connectivity at app restart.

Please check following answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18613257/9158543) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43622826/9158543) which are posted on StackOverflow by ex-employee of crashlytics companies