# How does fabric handle being offline?

Tags: google-fabric

I am interested in working with Fabric, how does the api work when not connected to the internet?

I found that firebase (a similar tool to this one) will store the data locally, then do a batch update to the server. However, anything over 72 hours will not be recorded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

We log the data locally and then send it on relaunch of the app with an active network connection. Answers events older then a week will not be recorded, but crashes will be.

Comment: Hi may I ask a follow-up question? We have some customers who *do have network connection*, but it may be very expensive for them. What we do today, we don't invoke Crashlytics in this scenario. But I'd prefer to be smarter, and launch Crashlytics in a special "low bandwidth" state. Is that possible today?

Comment: Of course you can :) Definitely understand that desire and need, but we don't have a solution for that aside from disabling Crashlytics. We do try to limit our network use, but if a user does have to pay per day or has very low limits of network usage due to cost, disabling us is probably better for your users.

Comment: SO explicitly instructs us not to write *thanks*, but I cannot abstain. Thank you and please add this feature request to the backlog on behalf of the 'next billion'.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Another follow up question. Some of our customers' devices are never connected to the internet. They are connected to our custom servers which are connected to the internet. Is there any way for us to use Fabric solutions by maybe routing the calls through our server?

Comment: No, we don't have support for custom routing.

Comment: Will Firbase crashlytics obey the same rules of Fabric?