# Android Crashlytics offline behaviour: When application have no internet accss

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have some android applications which usually have no internet access most of the time but there are some times which they can access internet.

1. I want to know if I embed Crashlytics in my application, will it keep a log of application crash reports when my phone is offline and submit them when user phone can access internet or not?

If answer is yes:

2. How much logs will be recorded (or may be I should ask how much android `logcat` keep error logs)?
3. How crash submit process will be scheduled? Will it be started eventually after accessing internet or it will be start when my application starts and it have internet access or any other things?

Comment: You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621703/how-does-fabric-handle-being-offline/43622826#43622826. but not full information you want :D

Comment: @CôngHải Will **Firbase** crashlytics keep the same implementations of the **Fabric** one?

Comment: it's same I think. Fabric already merge to Firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebaser here -

As mentioned in the comment to your main post by Công Hải, [How does fabric handle being offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621703/how-does-fabric-handle-being-offline/43622826#43622826) still applies - crashes will be stored locally until there's a chance to upload them.

It will attempt to send those up as soon as two conditions are met - the app is relaunched after crashing and the device is connected to the internet.