# Android Application Debugging - How to handle issue 'App has stopped. open App again'?

Tags: android, debugging

My Android App is going through End user testing. It is being used in the moving bus. Sometimes while running we get error:

AppName has stopped
Open App again.

Is there way to capture the stack trace / error  whenever this issue comes so that it is easier to debug and fix?

One way I can think of is to run the App while connected with the Computer and then check the error. Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to release the memory by making the variables null when User moves to different screen. If the function is called again then also I am initialising the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such "surprises" it'd be good if you'd use something like [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics).
Firebase Crashlytics is just a crash-reporter. 
I'd not offer you to use Crashlytics from Fabric, 'cause they [will support it until 31 March 2020](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap?utm_campaign=discover&utm_medium=natural), after that only Firebase will be used.

You'll be notified each time when something went wrong on the devices of your users and for you will be available the stacktrace for occurred error.

Comment: That's good suggestion. Thank you. But if App crashes when there is no Internet connectivity then I guess in that case  I will not get any notification. Is there any way to debug the crash? Can I write any global error handler which will be triggered if App crashes due to any function in the entire App, and it will write the stack trace on the device? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ashwanikumar , even if there's any internet connection you'll get the crash but with the delay till the user will have an active connection.
You can read this question to clarify everything for yourself
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618098/8797900

Comment: gromyk Sir, Loads and Tons of thanks. With your suggestion I was able to capture the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fabric/Firebase Crashlytics. When your app crashes, it will give you crash information with device details.

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics